# How to fix fadeOut effect only working once in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Noob here, I'm validating a file input form using jquery and I want a message to display when file extensions are incorrect, I have done so that a message appears and and it fades out but it only works once and I want it to work everytime they try to submit form.

Here's what I have.

```
<form id="file_upload" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="fileToUpload" id="exampleInputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
                            <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Favor de subir un archivo valido no mas de 2MB (.pdf, .docx, .doc, .xlsx, .txt).</small>
                            <span class="helper-text"></span>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn submit-archivo">Submit</button>
                    </form>
```

And this is the js script:

```
$("#file_upload").submit(function(e) { 
                e.preventDefault();
                helper_text = $('.helper-text');
                if(document.getElementById("exampleInputFile").files.length == 0){
                    helper_text.css("color", "red");
                    helper_text.html('Campo requerido.');
                    helper_text.fadeOut(3000, function() { $(this).remove(); });
                }

                var ext = $('#exampleInputFile').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
                    if($.inArray(ext, ['doc','docx','pdf','ppt', 'pptx', 'xlsx', 'xls', 'csv', 'txt', 'pdf', 'zip', 'rar']) == -1){
                        helper_text.css("color", "red");
                        helper_text.html('Archivo no valido.');
                        helper_text.fadeOut(3000, function() { $(this).remove(); });
                    }
            });
```

Comment: $(this).remove(); removes the element from html therefore the next time there is nothing in $('.helper-text'). Why are you removing it after fading out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you are removing the element in the callback function for fadeout, so it gets removed from the DOM.

second, after calling fadeout it will not display since the element will be hidden, so you can do something like fadeIn to show it again.

see below for what you are trying to achieve. i moved the functionality into an if block since it was calling it twice when you check the file length and when you check the extension type.

```js
$("#file_upload").submit(function(e) { 
                e.preventDefault();
                helper_text = $('.helper-text');
                var show_fadeout = false;
                if(document.getElementById("exampleInputFile").files.length == 0){
                 show_fadeout = true;
                }

                var ext = $('#exampleInputFile').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
                    if($.inArray(ext, ['doc','docx','pdf','ppt', 'pptx', 'xlsx', 'xls', 'csv', 'txt', 'pdf', 'zip', 'rar']) == -1){
                    show_fadeout = true;
                    }
                    
                    if(show_fadeout) {
                    helper_text.fadeIn();
                        helper_text.css("color", "red");
                        helper_text.html('Archivo no valido.');
                        helper_text.fadeOut(3000, function() {  });
                    }
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="file_upload" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="fileToUpload" id="exampleInputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
                            <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Favor de subir un archivo valido no mas de 2MB (.pdf, .docx, .doc, .xlsx, .txt).</small>
                            <span class="helper-text"></span>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn submit-archivo">Submit</button>
                    </form>
```

Comment: This helped, thank you so much! Plus it helped with the whole don't repeat yourself.